# Gif image not animating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Why is the gif image not animating when I set it to page using jquery or javascript ?

```
var loadingImage = '<img src="./assets/img/loading.gif">';
$("#loading-div").html(loadingImage);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a loading image right before executing a time-consuming synchronous JS code, e.g.:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {}
```

Then the JS will freeze the UI and the image won't animate. In some cases, it is possible to leverage the work to a [WebWorker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Using_web_workers) as to don't freeze the UI, but often it is more effort than it's worth.

Also, in some browsers, if you add a gif right before moving away to another page, it won't animate as well.

These are the most frequent use cases where `gif`s don't animate in my experience, hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a problem in your code. I just created a fiddle with the same code.

http://jsfiddle.net/FmReg/

```
var loadingImage = '<img src="http://fc05.deviantart.net/fs71/f/2013/176/3/e/banana_jam_by_hat_kid-d6anoqh.gif">';
$("#loading-div").html(loadingImage);
```

This should be a problem with either image path or because of the corrupt image.